# Can't open PDF file downloaded from CodeIgniter

Tags: codeigniter, pdf, download

I try to download a PDF file from a server. The download is successful, but I get this error when I open the file in Adobe Reader:

[image: Adobe Reader error]

When I try to download file manually from the server, it works.

Code to download the file based on CodeIgniter framework:

```
function downloadFile($file){
    force_download('assets/img/file/'.$file, NULL);
}
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: Can you open the original copy of the file present on the server? Please check if the file on the server is valid and can be opened. Then try and have a look over the file which is downloaded.

Comment: hello @AtishAgrawal, i tried to opened the original file on the server and its oke, no problem with the file. i think the problem here is when i want to download the file, seem like there's some corrupt of the file when i tried to download

Comment: You don't seem to be outputting headers for the file to be downloaded, this is probably causing the file to be transferred in the incorrect mode, with an incorrect mime type, etc. Also, are you loading the file helper with `$this->load->helper('download')`? it looks like you are not, and that would cause a PHP error streamed instead of the file, which would end up transferring a corrupt PDF file

Comment: @JavierLarroulet I've user correct MIME Type and added download helper in autoload
when I run this code in localhost, its fine
do you think its a server problem ?

Answer (score 1):

```
function downloadFile($file){
    $this->load->helper('download');
    force_download('assets/img/file/'.$file, NULL);
}
```

If you don't load the download helper, the `force_download` function will not be available, thus generating a PHP error which ends up being a corrupt downloaded file

Comment: I added it on autoload and i try your answer but still not working